# How to use UTF-8 encoded command in AppleScript's do shell script on OS X 10.4

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I have a program that generates a shell script and runs it via apple script. My output is UTF-8 encoded and I can't change that. On OS X 10.6 and above that works fine. On OS X 10.4 (Tiger) my script fails as soon as the file names /paths I need to process contain diacritical marks like é,à,Ü etc. (I don't have a 10.5 to try with so I don't know about that one yet)

I assume that this is a problem with the locale.

```
do shell script "locale"
```

gives me:

```
"LANG=
LC_COLLATE=\"C\"
LC_CTYPE=\"C\"
LC_MESSAGES=\"C\"
LC_MONETARY=\"C\"
LC_NUMERIC=\"C\"
LC_TIME=\"C\"
LC_ALL="
```

so I figured that starting my script with:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8;
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8;
```

might help but it turn out that it still does not work.

What else can I do to make the utf-8 encoded shell script work on OS X 10.4
can I make UTF-8 work in some other way or can I convert it to the default character encoding the system uses?

**EDIT:**

It turned out that starting with the export statements I had thought of:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8;
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8;
```

does answer my original question.

This works:

```
do shell script " export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; touch /ü"
```

My problem turned out to be that I need to use osascript to be able to immediately return the shell to the process that spawns it like this:

```
set myScriptAsString to "do shell script \" export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; touch /ü\""
do shell script "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; osascript -e " & quoted form of myScriptAsString & " > /dev/null 2> /dev/null & "
```

and no matter where I put the exports there it does not work with osascript...

Comment: I was trying to use `tr` to translate accented characters to their non-accented counterparts (e.g. áé to ae) and while it worked well in the Terminal, it was returning "UeUo" when run in an applescript. Inserting `export 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8' ; ` at the beginning of the `do shell script` convinced it to generate the correct output. While it's unrelated to your problem, thinking about this question was the first step to figuring it out, so +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem on **OS X 10.5**

The `osascript`command on **OS X 10.4** doesn't handle UTF-8 encoded text correctly when the string contain extended ASCII character.

Solution : Use the `MacRoman` encoding, `osascript` handle it without problem.

```
set myScriptAsString to quoted form of "do shell script \"touch /ü\""
do shell script "tString=$(echo " & myScriptAsString & "| iconv -t MACROMAN -f UTF8-MAC); osascript -e \"$tString\" > /dev/null 2> /dev/null & "
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. This won't work for greek, cyrilic, japanese etc. but it's a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You have saved me from suicide… not for the many hours trying to use an automator Service script to process SublimeText and copying also with pbcopy… I tried it long time before.  Nothing.  I simply do now

```
`echo '#{s.sub(/\s+$/, '')}'  | iconv -t MACROMAN -f UTF8-MAC  | pbcopy`
```

### Thanks!

Comment: Wow, this saved me from suicide! I was using the `Copy to clipboard` action before, and `åäö` would end up as `åäö` (looks the same visually, but try it [here](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php) to see the difference). Using `echo \`<shell command>  | iconv -t MACROMAN -f UTF8-MAC  | pbcopy\`` instead solved my issues.